# Show 0 when count(*) query from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm running a query on one table to get a count of all the different errors that the data highlights. Most days there should be 0 errors. As a result, no records will appear in the result by the groupings. What I want is a record for each grouping to appear but to show a 0 in the `count(*)` column if there aren't any errors. How can I do this?

```
select ITEM_CODE, NBR, CATEGORY, count(*) as ERR_CNT
from ITEM_TRCKR
where (
       DATEDIFF(dd,[ITM_SENT_DT],GETDATE()) > 1
         AND [DSBRSMNT_RECVD_DT] = 'NULL'
   )
group by
ITEM_CODE, NBR, CATEGORY
```

Comment: Please show an example of the resultset you want.

Comment: Not related to the question you asked, but one thing I noticed in your query - `DATEDIFF(dd,[ITM_SENT_DT],GETDATE()) > 1` is better written as as `[ITM_SENT_DT] < DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`. Why? So the storage engine doesn't have to do date math against every row in your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all groupings, use a `cross join` to generate them then a `left join` to bring in the additional information:

```
select i.ITEM_CODE, n.NBR, c.CATEGORY,
       count(it.item_code) as ERR_CNT
from (select distinct item_code from ITEM_TRCKR) i cross join
     (select distinct nbr from item_trkr) n cross join
     (select distinct category from item_trkr) c left join
     item_trkr it
     on it.item_code = i.item_code and
        it.nbr = n.nbr and
        it.category = c.cateogry and
        DATEDIFF(day, it.ITM_SENT_DT, GETDATE()) > 1 and
        it.DSBRSMNT_RECVD_DT is null
group by i.ITEM_CODE, n.NBR, c.CATEGORY;
```

I assume that `it.DSBRSMNT_RECVD_DT` is a date.  Hence the `NULL` comparison should be to the SQL concept `NULL`, not to the string `'NULL'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have at least one record per day (with or without an error), one option is to do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    item_code, 
    nbr, 
    category, 
    sum(case when dsbrsmnt_recvd_dt] = 'null' then 1 else 0 end) as err_cnt
from item_trckr
where [itm_sent_dt] < cast(getdate() as date) 
group by item_code, nbr, category
```

Note that `<expr> = 'null'` actually checks the `exr` against litteral string `'null'`. If what you want is count the `null` values in the column, you can leverage the fact that `count(<expr>)` ignore `null`s:

```
select 
    item_code, 
    nbr, 
    category, 
    count(*) - count(dsbrsmnt_recvd_dt) err_cnt
from item_trckr
where [itm_sent_dt] < cast(getdate() as date) 
group by item_code, nbr, category
```